# Adding additional Storage domain NFS for ovirt 3.5

Tags: nfs, network-attached-storage, ovirt

I wanted to add an additional storage domain for my ovirt setup, but my problem is that everytime I try to add the Data / NFS I get this error:

```
2015-09-23 16:07:46,752 ERROR [org.ovirt.engine.core.vdsbroker.vdsbroker.CreateStorageDomainVDSCommand] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8702-4) [34173edf] Failed in CreateStorageDomainVDS method
2015-09-23 16:07:46,755 ERROR [org.ovirt.engine.core.vdsbroker.vdsbroker.CreateStorageDomainVDSCommand] (ajp--127.0.0.1-8702-4) [34173edf] Command CreateStorageDomainVDSCommand(HostName = oVirt-Intel00, HostId = 72ccbe3f-7327-4f19-83ed-6fbceb6fcd37, storageDomain=StorageDomainStatic[export_domain, 34023a97-e603-4406-b796-68ebb3fa48a8], args=192.168.3.60:/export/ovirt) execution failed. Exception: VDSErrorException: VDSGenericException: VDSErrorException: Failed to CreateStorageDomainVDS, error = Error creating a storage domain: ('storageType=1, sdUUID=34023a97-e603-4406-b796-68ebb3fa48a8, domainName=export_domain, domClass=3, typeSpecificArg=192.168.3.60:/export/ovirt domVersion=0',), **code = 351**
```

I have tried manually mounting the exported path and it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NFS exports have some extra requirements - they should be exported and accessible by all the hypervisors of course, but also, the export path should belong to 36:36

`chown -R 36:36 /path/to/export`

Folks usually forget the permissions. BTW, if you are using SELinux on the NFS machine, please make sure it is configured for NFS as well

Comment: Thanks a lot. yes people tend to forget about this